# dúvida com abrir e fechar conexão

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

gostaria da ajuda de vocês com a conexão abaixo, quando fecho tenho o seguinte erro abaixo, estou fazendo da forma correta? com relação a abertura e fechamento da conexão?

minha pool

```
public class MysqlConnectionPool {
private final DataSource dataSource;

public MysqlConnectionPool() {
    MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource pool = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
    pool.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://*********.sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/*********?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false");
    pool.setUser("*********");
    pool.setPassword("*********");

    this.dataSource = pool;
}    
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    return connection;
}}
```

Exemplo de um DAO que tenho, todo os outros seguem o mesmo padrão

```
public class UsuarioDAO {
ExceptionHandling capturaException = new ExceptionHandling();
GeradorURL geradorURL = new GeradorURL();
MysqlConnectionPool mysqlConnectionPool;
private final Connection connection;

public UsuarioDAO() throws SQLException {
    this.connection = new MysqlConnectionPool().getConnection();
}

public List<UsuarioDTO> seleciona() throws SQLException {
    List<UsuarioDTO> results = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "select aqui";
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery()) {

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            results.add(populaConta(resultSet));
        }
        resultSet.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        capturaException.ExceptionHandlerController(e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
         connection.close();
    }
    return results;
}}
```

erro

> 02-Jan-2018 15:49:16.027 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-5]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/Head2Head] threw
>   exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   No operations allowed after connection closed.] with root cause
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   No operations allowed after connection closed.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente você fechou a conexão e depois tentou usa-la. Por isso do *error* !
Fecha todas as conexão dentro ***finally***  isso pode ajudar.

```
  finally {
     connection.close();
     resultSet.close();
     stmt.close();
  }
```

Onde você está chamando ou usando a sua classe UsuarioDAO.java?